# Fire only server validators of user controls that are displayed

Tags: .net, validation, user-controls

On some page, I have a repeater with user controls inside that contain a textbox and a custom validator which checks the content of the textbox. The logic of the validator should remain as it is if possible.
The controls are rendered, but by default not displayed. The user can display them by checking a checkbox (launching a jQuery script), so they are marked as "added". Now, if the user clicks save button, **only the validators of controls that are displayed should fire**. At the moment, all validators fire which isn´t desired.

 
**Update**
I have by default disabled the validators in code behind

```
controlValidator.Enabled = false;
```

and tried to enable them in the jQuery script.
However, this has no effect.

```
$val = $(this).find(".controlCell").find(".controlValidator");
$val.removeAttr('disabled');
```

I can find the validator by it´s css class (not the ID).

Comment: I guess you could try disabling the validators along with hiding them.

Answer (score 0):

You can add **ValidationGroup** attribute to the added controls.Now, you can control on the asp.net controls that you want to validate.

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge, you can disable the controls along with making them invisible something like below:

```
$("#<%ControlID.ClientID%>").attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

Hope this Helps!!